# Function to store sg.Text() values in an Excel worksheet? (Python)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, user-interface

Im using simplepygui and pandas in order to createa functioning menu that will store Name, Site, Mealt Time, Cost, and the order itself in this format " Burger, Onions, Pickles, Drinks"

Is there any way that I can store these values in the excel worksheet?

If I use the text box right next tothe the "Total" to actually input the calculated total, it willstore, but I cannot fiure out how to make it store in excel without having to manually input it into the input text box.

Here is my code block for this program:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd

menu_dictionary = {
    "Cheese":0.50,
    "Sandwhich":1.75,
    "Pickles":0.25,
    "Hot Dog":1.25,
    "Burger": 3.5,
    "Onions": 0.75,
    "Bacon": 1.25,
    "Eggs": 1.00,
    "Fries": 1.25,
    "Chips": 1.25,
    "Salad": 1.25,
    "Potatoes": 1.25,
    "Ranch": 1.25,
    "Ketchup": 1.25,
    "BBQ": 1.25,
    "Drinks": 1.25,
}

Total=0
items = []
Name = ''
sg.theme("DarkTeal9")

EXCEL_FILE= 'MenuTest1.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE)

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Welcom to the MAF Menu ")],
    [sg.Text('Name'), sg.InputText(key='Name'),sg.Text('Site'), sg.Combo(["A01", "B01", "C01", "D01", "E01", "F01", "G01", "H01", "I01", "J01", "K01", "L01", "M01", "N01", "O01"], key='Site')],
    [sg.Text("Total $" + str(Total), key='Total'), sg.InputText(key='Cost')],
    [sg.Text('Meal Time'),
                    sg.Checkbox('Breakfast', key='Breakfast'),
                    sg.Checkbox('Lunch', key='Lunch'),
                    sg.Checkbox('Dinner', key='Dinner')],
    [sg.Text("Entrees"), sg.Button("Burger"), sg.Button("Sandwhich"), sg.Button("Hot Dog"), sg.Button("Eggs")],
    [sg.Text("Toppings"), sg.Button("Onions"), sg.Button("Pickles"), sg.Button("Cheese")],
    [sg.Text("Sides"), sg.Button("Fries"), sg.Button("Chips"), sg.Button("Salad"), sg.Button("Potatoes")],
    [sg.Text('Condiments'), sg.Button("Ranch"), sg.Button("Ketchup"), sg.Button("BBQ")],
    [sg.Text("Beverages"), sg.Button("Drinks")],
    [sg.Button("Review"), sg.Text(Name, key='Order')],
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Button("Clear"), sg.Exit()],
]

window = sg.Window('Sample', layout)

def clear_input():

    for key in values:
        window['Order'].update('')
        items = []
        Name = ''
        Total = 0
        window['Total'].update("Total $0")
        window[key]('')
    return None


while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == 'Clear':
        clear_input()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "Exit":
        break

    if event == 'Submit':
       
        df = df.append(values, ignore_index=True)
        df.to_excel(EXCEL_FILE, index=False)
        sg.popup('Data Stored')
        clear_input()

    if event == "Review":

        order = ", ".join(items)
        order = "{}'s Order: {}".format(Name, order)
        x = Name + order + " for $" + str(Total)

        window['Order'].update(x)

    if event in menu_dictionary:
        Total = Total + menu_dictionary[event]
        if event not in items:
            items.append(event)
        window['Total'].update("Total $" + str(Total))


window.close()
```

Here is the output:
[Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHTIE.png)
[ExcelWorkbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wTWT.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to read sg.Text elements. In my case their values are set programmatically, not by a user. They are displayed to the user, but need to be saved when the form is submitted.

Been trying to understand how to use the .Widget property to access the underlying gui toolkit, in my case tkinter.

> print(type(window[elementKey].Widget))

yields the class name for the underlying tkinter widget, but trying to read the properties is not working for me using:

> ```
>    w = win["-GPD-"].Widget
>    for key in w:
>        print(w[key])
> ```

The debugger shows the value of w to be:
.!toplevel.!frame2.!frame.!frame3.!labelframe.!frame2
not the tkinter Label object I expected based on the `print(type(window[elementKey].Widget))` line above which produces:

> <class 'tkinter.Label'>